# How to vectorize:  set a value based on last time a binary vector was 1

Tags: r, finance, trading, xts

I have another R beginner question...

How can I vectorize (avoid for loop in) following code:

```
# algorithm for getting entry prices (when signal > 0): look back from current
# position until you find first signal > 0,
# `mktdataclose` at that time is entry price
# `entryPrices` is an xts object representing entry prices
# if entryPrices are not available (is.null == TRUE) then wee need to reconstruct
# them from signal (xts object with 1 when entry signal triggered and 0 
# otherwise) and close prices available in mktdataclose (an xts object with the
# same length as signal and same dates just that it represents closing prices)

EntryPrices <- entryPrices
if (is.null(EntryPrices)) {
    # get entryprices as close prices on buy signal
    EntryPrices <- ifelse(signal > 0, mktdataclose, 0)
    entryPrice <- 0
    for (i in 1:NROW(signal)) {
        if (signal[i] > 0) entryPrice <- mktdataclose[i]
        EntryPrices[i] <- entryPrice
    }
}
```

I am stuck at thinking SAS data step way and desperatley looking for retain etc. Where can I find some simple exaples in order to understand sapply etc (r help via ?sapply is unfortunately to complicated for me... :( )

Thank you for your kind help.

Best,
Samo.

Comment: It's hard to see what is actually going on without a reproducible example (i.e. with vectors that look like your data). But in the code above, doesn't the `ifelse` statement do exactly the same as the loop after it?

Comment: You code doesn't make sense to me without an example; you ask for the number of rows of `signal`, but then index `signal` as if it were a vector. If `signal` is a vector then `seq_along(signal)` is sufficient to initiate the loop variable `i`. It is inconsistencies such as this that makes it difficult to say how to proceed. We could give a solution where `signal` is a vector or a matrix, but only one would match your problem - thus wasted time and effort. So please show a simple example of data that we can reproduce and use.

Comment: `NROW` seems to differ from `nrow` in that it treats a vector as a one-column matrix. So I guess that `signal` is intended to be a vector here. But yeah it is pretty confusing.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help. Will edit the question with reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your problem is: you have two vectors `signal` and `mktdataclose` of length `n`, and you want to create a new vector `EntryPrices` of length `n` such that `mktdataclose[i]` is the value of `mktdataclose` the *last* time `signal` was 1 at or before time `i`. You can do this without a for loop, using `cummax`, an often unexpectedly useful function (Note that this question is similar in flavor to some of your earlier questions, which were similarly solved using this function and `cumsum`). Here we go, using Gavin's data:

```
set.seed(123)
signal <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
mktdataclose <- runif(10, 1, 10)
```

Our problem is really to convert the `signal` vector into a vector of the appropriate indices:

```
indices <- cummax( seq_along(signal) * signal)
```

This is exactly the `indices` we want, except for the 0. Now we set `EntryPrices` by extracting the values at the non-zero `indices` from `mktdataclose`:

```
EntryPrices <- c( rep(0, sum(indices==0)), mktdataclose[ indices ])

>   cbind(signal, indices, mktdataclose, EntryPrices)
      signal indices mktdataclose EntryPrices
 [1,]      0       0     9.611500    0.000000
 [2,]      1       2     5.080007    5.080007
 [3,]      0       2     7.098136    5.080007
 [4,]      1       4     6.153701    6.153701
 [5,]      1       5     1.926322    1.926322
 [6,]      0       5     9.098425    1.926322
 [7,]      1       7     3.214790    3.214790
 [8,]      1       8     1.378536    1.378536
 [9,]      1       9     3.951286    3.951286
[10,]      0       9     9.590533    3.951286
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer @Prasad --- I was racking my brain trying to think of a way to do this but could only handle special cases. I can now delete my Answer as you identify the problem **and** solve it where I was just trying to point out the problem that several posters had missed.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, it helped that I answered a similar question before :)

Comment: Prasad, thanx again for your another perfect answer. I hope I now understand the cummax and cumsum tricks... :)

Answer (score 0):

since signal is 0 and 1 i presume you can vectorize with:

```
EntryPrices * signal
```

Comment: I think he wants to vectorize the inner loop and and that depends on previous values of `mktdataclose` because `entryPrice` is only updated (from starting point 0) when `signal > 0`. As such, your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @darcken Thanks for your help. I did not specify enough what I want. @Gavin Yes, I want to carry last value when signal[i]==1 to subsequent steps in for loop until new signal == 1 comes in...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that you may find more straight-forward.  I'm using Prasad's psudo-data.

```
> EntryPrices <- ifelse(signal > 0, mktdataclose, NA)
> EntryPrices <- na.locf(EntryPrices, na.rm=FALSE)
> cbind(signal,mktdataclose,EntryPrices)
      signal mktdataclose EntryPrices
 [1,]      0     9.611500          NA
 [2,]      1     5.080007    5.080007
 [3,]      0     7.098136    5.080007
 [4,]      1     6.153701    6.153701
 [5,]      1     1.926322    1.926322
 [6,]      0     9.098425    1.926322
 [7,]      1     3.214790    3.214790
 [8,]      1     1.378536    1.378536
 [9,]      1     3.951286    3.951286
[10,]      0     9.590533    3.951286
```